# How do I switch from geth only to using geth + Mist, or parity + Mist?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist

I was using geth (have quite a few accounts in here too) from the command line only on a different computer. I moved the files in keystore over to this computer I have now.

With the bug, all my balances show up as 0 on my other computer. The 1.4.12 hotfix seemed to only fix the crashing.

I want to switch over to something else for now at least and start using this computer for Ethereum management. When I open up Mist, accounts aren't automatically added from the keystore folder. Not sure how this program works yet.

What do I do with the files in my AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\keystore that I copied from the other computer folder to import it into Mist? Hopefully the geth bug gets fixed soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### From geth to Mist:

- just run `geth` as you usually do.
- in addition, run `Mist` or `Ethereum-Wallet`
- the browser will automatically detect your running node and connect to it

#### From geth to parity:

- don't run `geth`.
- run `parity --geth`, it will copy over your keys from the `geth` keystore directory automatically and import them properly
- have fun using parity, for example attach geth with `geth attach` to parity.
- Mist should also work on top of that, like described above, but it's a bit buggy.